# whenever I am trying to navigate to another page, react-navigation is pushing me to the previous page

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I find difficulty navigating to another page using react-native-navigation,
the workflow which I am looking for is A -> B and then when I press any button in B should go to A,
what is happening whenever I am clicking the button in A it is going to B but without clicking any button it is redirecting me to A again, the same issue happens in the bottom tab navigator too.

this is my code for stack and bottom tab navigator,

```
function MyTabs() {
    const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
                headerShown: false,
                tabBarShowLabel: false,
                gestureEnabled: false,
                tabBarStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Color.Black : Color.White,
                    borderTopWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: isDarkMode ? Color.White : Color.White,
                    height: 80,
                },
                tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
                    <View>
                        {route.name === 'Profile' ? (
                            <MaterialIcons
                                name="person"
                                size={30}
                                color={isDarkMode ? (focused ? Color.White : Color.DarkGrey) : (focused ? Color.Black : Color.LightGrey)}
                                style={{
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    marginTop: 10
                                }}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <Image
                                source={Images.Explore}
                                resizeMode="contain"
                                style={{
                                    width: 30,
                                    height: 30,
                                    tintColor: isDarkMode ? (focused ? Color.White : Color.DarkGrey) : (focused ? Color.Black : Color.LightGrey),
                                    marginTop: 8
                                }}
                            />
                        )}
                    </View>
                ),
                tabBarLabelStyle: {
                    fontSize: 15,
                }
            })}
        >
            <Tab.Screen name="Explore" component={Explore} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                initialRouteName="Splash"
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown: false,

                }}
            >
                <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                <Stack.Screen name="BottomTabs" component={MyTabs} options={{ headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false, }} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for screen B instead

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need to know this
[click here](https://snack.expo.dev/?platform=web)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).